# Devops comments removed when AD account is removed/disabled

Tags: azure-devops

Hopefully, this isn't a duplicate request. We've recently moved to Azure Devops for our source control, but have noticed that a user's comments are deleted if their respective AD account is deleted/disabled when they leave the company.

Is this something we should expect to happen, or should any contributions (like comments) be left behind when the AD account is deleted?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but without success. After I removed a user from AAD, all his comments in the work item and pull request remained. Could you provide some more specific information, so that we study further? For example, does your "AD account" refer to AAD account or Azure Devops account? If you mean Azure DevOps account, does your organization link to AAD? Where do you mean when you say the comment was deleted?

Comment: Hi, I haven't received your latest news. Is there any update for this issue?